# How to use OSX command line GUI emacs as git $EDITOR

Tags: osx, git, gui-emacs, command-line-arguments

I have a script to launch OSX GUI emacs from command line at:

`/usr/local/bin/emacs`

The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
$(/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --chdir $PWD "$@") &
```

I have configured a bash `$EDITOR` environment variable:

`export EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/emacs`

I want git to open the GUI emacs for commit messages and rebase messages

If I try to commit:

```
evs-MBP:skeletal-animation-system kev$ echo "cool" >> fake.js
Kevs-MBP:skeletal-animation-system kev$ git add fake.js
Kevs-MBP:skeletal-animation-system kev$ git commit
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

This will launch the GUI prepopulated with the correct commit prompt however I believe because the command runs in the emacs command runs in the background git thinks it immediately quits.

Similiar undesired behavior happens with a rebase.

```
Kevs-MBP:skeletal-animation-system kev$ git rebase -i origin/master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rebase-test.
```

The rebase is automatically completed. I'm assuming again because the processes detaches and git thinks it completed.

I'm looking for a way to use GUI emacs with the git command line tool.

Comment: Remove that & sign at the end of the second line of your script to make the app stay in the foreground so git does not think the editor quit. The canonical approach is to put an editor variable in .gifconfig file instead and let git open Emacs anytime it needs editing input.

Comment: can I put my emacs script in the .gitconfig?

Comment: no, check this for config examples: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 1):

For my settings I have the following:

the shell script:
`#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"`

In my `.zshrc`: `export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/emacsclient"`

In my `init.el`: `(global-git-commit-mode t)`

With these settings any git work from the command line moves to the GUI emacs.

Comment: getting this `Symbol’s function definition is void: global-git-commit-mode` when evaling

Comment: Check the help string for the function but you may have to do `setq` as part of it

Comment: this might require that you have [magit](https://magit.vc) installed, if you don't already (and you should install it if you haven't already done so).

Answer (score 1):

Just set your EDITOR to run `emacsclient -a "" -c` (yours will be at `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient`, I personally use some symbolic links to make life easier). Problem solved.  The `global-git-commit-mode` is nice but not necessary.  When you're done editing the message, save and `C-x #` to close the buffer and stop the emacsclient process.

The `'-a ""'` option to emacsclient will cause a new emacs in daemon mode to be started if it's not already.  The `-c` option opens up a new GUI frame, otherwise if you didn't have one open already it would open up a terminal frame.

However, if you haven't already, you should look into `magit`. No finer integration between git and Emacs exists.